# How to use primefaces on cloudbees glassfish server

Tags: primefaces, glassfish, cloudbees

We are developing an Java EE webapp on a glassfish 4 server running in the cloubeees cloud. We want to use Primefaces 3.5 . Our app runs perfectly on a local glassfish server after we copied the commons-fileupload.jar into the lib domain/lib folder. When we push the app into the cloud it isnt deployed the log says:

Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem

So i think the server misses the fileupload.jar, but we dont have acces to the server administration console or the folder structure. Does anyone here used Primefaces in the cloudbees cloud or knows a other way to fix the problem?

best regards 
Peter!

Comment: Did you try adding commons-fileupload to WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. We solved the problem! It was caused by another error, which stopped the deployment to cloudbees. :)

Comment: I dont know where you landed but I have tried primefaces with jelastic http://jelastic.com/docs/primefaces and it worked very well. What is the solution you tried to sort this out..